# pyplot.savefig() stops after few files and gives [Error 13] permission denied

Tags: python, wav

I have been trying to get mfcc of .wav files using `librosa` library and saving the plot as `.jpg`. After running for some files, program stops and I get the error

```
"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:/Users/shaur/csye7105/audio_data/mfccs_3sec/Speaker0034_019_chunk7.jpg'
```

Here's my code for generating mfcc

```
def generate_mfcc(intial_directory, final_directory, no_of_coefficients):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(initial_directory,audio_file_folder_name)):
        filepath = initial_directory+'/'+audio_file_folder_name+'/'+file;
        mfcc_image_prefix = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
        y, sr = librosa.load(filepath)
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y, n_mfcc = no_of_coefficients, sr = sr)
        plt.figure(figsize = (25,10))
        librosa.display.specshow(mfccs, x_axis = 'time', sr = sr)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        for i, mfccs in enumerate(mfccs):
            
            fig.savefig(final_directory+"/"+mfcc_image_prefix+'.jpg')
```

Comment: you get problem in line which uses `matplotlib`, not `librosa` but all problem is if you have folder `C:/Users/shaur/csye7105/audio_data/mfccs_3sec/` and if you have privileges to save in this file. So your problem is system settings, not code. OR maybe you have to first create this folder in code - `os.makedirs()`

Comment: in one place you use `os.path.join()` but in others `...+"/"+...` - you could use `os.path.join()` in all places